# IOS fb invites sent but not shown on users wall

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, apprequests, facebook-app-requests, facebook-invite

I am sending requests from my app to the fb friends but i am not getting any notification on the wall of fb user whom i sent request ?

I am using FB SDK 3.2 (i hope its the latest)

Following is the code i am using to send request

```
NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     friendList, @"to",
                                     nil];
    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just smashed %d friends! Can you beat it?", 15]
        title:@"Total Smashed Score"
        parameters:params
        handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
            } else {
                if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                    // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                    NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
                }
            }
        }
     ];
```

The request dialog is properly shown, when i click send button the invites are sent but not shown on the users wall. Any type of help will be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: hello buddy i have same problem also , u got answere or not if yes then plz share it

Comment: hey how did you solve your problem bro??

Comment: @Quality Coder - I have posted my solution, you can test it.

Comment: How did you get this friendList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
//friendlist = NSString of fb id's

NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     friendList, @"to",
                                     nil];
    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"message!"]
        title:@"title"
        parameters:params
        handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
            } else {
                if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                    // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                    NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                } else {
                    NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                    if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                        // User clicked the Cancel button
                        NSLog(@"User clicked cancel button.");
                    } else {
                        nslog("succesfully sent invites");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     ];
```

Comment: i dont know what is the change between the before and last code, but the first code didn't work, and this one worked like charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Invites are never shown on the user's wall / timeline. There are only viewable in private by the user they are sent to. The will show up on the [Requests page](http://www.facebook.com/appcenter/requests) or as a notification to the user.